# Retrieve audio data in JSON format and play it through Amazon Alexa

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am working on a custom lambda function in JavaScript for the Amazon Alexa. Amazon's docs have clear details on building custom skills, and I have successfully built several "stock" skills from their templates.

I am writing a unique skill now which must retrieve the JSON data located at this link: 
https://api.ense.nyc/latest

and then 'play' that data (since the data is snippets of audio) through the Alexa. I am not sure what to write to bring about this functionality.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this?  I think this isn't really the right forum for this sort of request for assistance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit complicated than your average stock skills, from the url it looks like a podcast skill.

You need to

Parse The JSON and get the audiourl from the list.
Set the skill state to PLAY_MODE.
Keep track of audio progress with audio event handlers.
Probably use a dynamodb alike database to persist incase your session ends and your audios are long so they keep on playing.

here is a sample skill, that parses a RSS feed for a podcast then plays the audios in a row

https://github.com/bespoken/streamer

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the audio files are short. In that case connect to the endpoint using an [http fetch library](https://gist.github.com/germanviscuso/ba0c8e5af0491a6cb88c39bd7cd5c0c7#file-index-js-L93) (eg. httpm module, node-fetch or axios in node.js). Once you get the json file navigate to the properties that have the audio, get the url, surround them by [audio tags](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html#audio) `<audio src="url"/>` ands send them in a standard speech response of your skill. The audio tag has time and quality limitations so if you run into issues the audio is probably longer or a different quality than expected.

Answer (score 0):

1)The audio should be available to public in (.mp3)
2)The audio should be in Alexa-friendly format

Converting audio files to an Alexa-friendly format using **Audacity**

1)Open the file to convert.
2)Set the **Project Rate** in the lower-left corner to *16000*.
3)Click **File > Export Audio** and change the Save as type to *MP3 Files*.
4)Click **Options**, set the **Quality** to *48 kbps* and the Bit Rate Mode to *Constant*.